# Oracle Apex 4.2 How to build a report with a selection list to filter the report

Tags: oracle, list, select, report, oracle-apex

hope You can help me.

Contents of `adresses` table:

```
 Name | Birthday   | Place
---------------------------------
 Mike | 01.01.1984 | London
 Anne | 01.01.1995 | Los Angeles
 Mary | 01.01.1993 | Los Angeles
```

This is the apex page I want to build:

```
Select List (shows All, London, Los Angeles) => <User chooses Los Angeles>

Selected = Los Angeles
```

Report "ADRESSES":

```
 Name | Birthday
-------------------
 Anne | 01.01.1995
 Mary | 01.01.1993
```

So what I want is to show a report with selected place, but don't show the column "Place" in the report, only in the select list.

How can I get this please?

I can create a select LIst for a column. But this is a select list inside the report.
How to create a select list for a column above the report, not inside the report?

Answer (score 3):

You would create a page item for the select list, e.g. P123_PLACE.  This could be in the same region as the report (you would want the region's Item Display Position set to "Above Content").

Then in the report you can add to the WHERE clause:

```
place = :P123_PLACE
```

If you want all rows returned when no place has been selected then do this:

```
(:P123_PLACE is null OR place = :P123_PLACE)
```

You can use a setting on the page item to submit the page whenever the select list is changed; this will refresh your report.  Alternatively you could have a button to fire the search.

Comment: This was helpful, thanks a lot! It's not a question of "condition", it's a where-condition in the sql-query. Thanks!!!!